# Is the linux kernel's list.h thread safe?

Tags: multithreading, kernel, linked-list

Is the linux kernel's list.h thread safe?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, the `list_head` struct doesn't contain any lock, and the operations are by no means atomic.

You can see so for yourself [here](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.31/include/linux/list.h), there is no mention of locking mechanisms etc.

Answer (score 6):

Just read the implementation; the answer is clearly NO in the presence of writers.  (Multiple readers on immutable data is safe.)

Paul McKenney gives an [introduction to RCU](http://lwn.net/Articles/262464/) on the ever-helpful LWN, from which you can glean some tips on managing thread-safe updates to linked lists.  Of course, your usage may be simple enough that spinlocks will suffice.